# Can non wandering sets be connected?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I know that the alpha and omega limit sets of a flow on a compact connected invariant subset of a manifold must be connected and these limit sets are contained in the non wandering set.

My question is whether the non-wandering set also has to be connected? If not, are there any counter-examples that can disprove this?

Comment: The flow $\dot x=\sin x$ on the reals has a disconnected non-wandering set. The glow $\dot x=0$ has a connected non-wandering set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you be more specific by explicitly writing the non-wandering sets for both the examples?

Comment: The non-wandering sets are the fixed points.

Comment: The flow is defined by $$\phi_{t}(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$

For $\dot{x} = 0$, we have $$\phi_{t}(x) = x$$

For this case: $$\phi_{t}(\mathbb{R}) \  \cap \ \mathbb{R} \neq \emptyset$$

and hence I can conclude that the entire real line(which is connected) is a non-wandering set. Is that right?@AnthonyQuas

Comment: Let $x\in\mathbb R$. Let $N$ be any neighbourhood of $x$. Then for any $T>0$, there exists $t>T$ such that $\phi_t(x)\in N$(in fact this is trivially true for all $t$). Hence, by the definition, $x$ is non-wandering.

Comment: From where can I study more examples on non-wandering set? @AnthonyQuas

Comment: I don’t think this is the right web site for this discussion. This should be covered in a basic textbook on dynamical systems.